# persistent audio playback in PHP web application - music shouldnt stop when navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, lumen, audio-player

I am trying to develop a simple music web browser based application using

- Lumen framework (5.1)
- AmplitudeJS library for playback - https://521dimensions.com/open-source/amplitudejs (i'm open to switch to another library, if it helps)

On a high level, this is what i did

- Created a simple master blade and extended it in all view files.
- I have setup the AmplitudeJS library to do playback. All works fine there.
- **but I want to make the player persistent i.e while navigating to other links in website the song must keep playing**

I've considered, tried but can't use (for reasons that are irrelevant to this discussion)

- loading the playback in a browser popup
- flash player
- or using something like history.js (history APIs) to retain state of the previous page
- iframes - loading player in a dedicated iframe, content in another frame etc
- Rewriting my code to use ajax, in a way that no REAL navigation happens, the content is always switched in the same page.. make it like a single page application.. (SEO problems.. If i can't find a better solution, this is what i would go with) (**Is there is a way the Ajax can be used without compromising the SEO? should probably be a separate question**)

I have also looked at the following, but couldn't figure out a definitive solution

- http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/render-view-without-layout
- [Laravel: how to render only one section of a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096241/laravel-how-to-render-only-one-section-of-a-template)
- [Audio Player: Constant playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210473/audio-player-constant-playing)
- [How to keep audio playing while navigating through pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555250/how-to-keep-audio-playing-while-navigating-through-pages)
- [Keeping audio player persistently/continuously playing while navigating HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260204/keeping-audio-player-persistently-continuously-playing-while-navigating-html-pag)
- [Keeping audio player persistently/continuously playing while navigating HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260204/keeping-audio-player-persistently-continuously-playing-while-navigating-html-pag)
- [Multiple Jplayer audio players from Laravel DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765078/multiple-jplayer-audio-players-from-laravel-db)

**let me know if i can provide any more info**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Frontend do you have? If it is  based on php that won't work. You need a persistent Javascript frontend like angularjs, emberjs, vue.js or whatever. Then you can have a master which doesn't get changed.

Comment: Yes the front-end is in PHP. @ki

Comment: PHP is not persistent is it? It reloads the page each time... or ma i wrong? Then the audio player is broken as well

Comment: yes PHP is not persistent . I have to concentrate on this (Is there is a way the Ajax can be used without compromising the SEO?) If there is no other way

Comment: If you have a multimedia rich site with strong javascript SEO is potentially compromised => But is there really so much text => content you need the bot to see? Google's self developed framework angularjs is as far as i now compromising the SEO, but you should really check on that, because Google is encorraging people to use this technology. At the end you can as well Program every site statically and if javascript rendering is activated => You can definitely check on that => You can turn on further navigation through a javascript view component to ensure user experience.

Comment: I think as well that times in  which static sites are in advance are changing. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I did search for that, google still not officially declared that angular and SEO concepts. And yes it's a multimedia rich website.